# Is there an inverse of System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, attributes, symbols

Is there an analogous conditional-not-present attribute or maybe a way to use the Conditional attribute to only include a method if that symbol is *not* defined?

What I'm looking for is something that works like this:

```
[Conditional("!SILVERLIGHT")]
private void DoStuffThatSilverlightCant() {...}
```

Such that the method will not be included if the symbol `SILVERLIGHT` does exist.

The reason I don't want to use a simple `#ifdef` is so that I can take advantage of the compiler removing the calling statements without having to wrap every individual call in an `#ifdef`.

Comment: As I was writing this question, it occurred to me that if it does exist, it actually wouldn't be helpful for what I was trying to do.  But, it seems like a good question anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:
The following code snippet only works if the #if is in every calling file which is not very practical.

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT
#define NOT_SILVERLIGHT
#endif

[Conditional("NOT_SILVERLIGHT")]
private void DoStuffThatSilverlightCant() {...}
```

What could be done however, is to have a build configuration for whatever platform you are using that will /define the needed symbol (NOT_SILVERLIGHT in that case).

Comment: That will only work in the file in which you declare the method.  It's not a global solution

Comment: That is a pretty good idea, though.  That certainly didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Jared: I stand corrected. I though the only place the define needed to be was with the function declaration and the calls would be optimized out. I usually only use the ConditionalAttribute with /define.